# How do you talk about things in parts?

Tags: word-choice, usage

I would like to say "It is written half in English and half in Japanese."

When writing this myself I came up with:

> これは半分英語で半分日本語で書いていました。

but I think that

> 半分英語で半分日本語で

does not sound very natural?

Comment: I don't understand what you tried to say by 書けています. Shouldn't 'It is written~~' be '書いてあります' or '書かれています', not '書いていました'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that

> 半分英語で半分日本語で

is fine. I think you could also say:

> 半分英語、半分日本語で

Answer (score 2):

Using `半分` like that is completely fine. You can use other fractions as well (but in that case, you cannot use it adverbially and have to insert the particle `を` or `は` after it like `三分の二を`). But if you do not particularly need to emphasize the act of writing, simply `書きました` is more natural than `書いていました`.